# accessing to google api in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-plus, sharing

I want to access to google's APIs in Unity3d. I want to use google plus API in my Unity3d application to have sharing feature in the app.
Please help me if you worked with google's APIs in Unity3d.
Thanks.

Comment: To help you, we need more context. What are you trying to do, specifically? What have you already done? What errors are you seeing?

Comment: Hey u find any solution or way to do this??

Answer (score 0):

There is a detailed explanation of how to do this [here](https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/csharp) for C#/.NET. You will at most have to make only minor changes to the code to make it work with Mono. One thing to note, is that you will have to include this code in order to tell Mono to allow the requests to the API. [(source)](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/249052/accessing-google-apis-in-unity.html)

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Security;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

public class UnsafeSecurityPolicy {

public static bool Validator(
object sender,
X509Certificate certificate,
X509Chain chain,
SslPolicyErrors policyErrors) {

//*** Just accept and move on...
Debug.Log ("Validation successful!");
return true;
}

public static void Instate() {

ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = Validator;
}
}
```

You will have to call Instate before you start using the API.